# The dimension of the space of cusp forms

Tags: number-theory, riemann-surfaces, automorphic-forms

In the book "Introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic functions", section 2.6, Shimura gives general formulas to compute the dimension of the space of integral and cusp forms of a given weight, for any Fuchsian group of the first kind. His proof uses the theory of divisors of automorphic forms and Riemann-Roch theorem.

Does anybody know if there is a general proof of these results which does not rely on the Riemann-Roch theorem (for every Fuchsian group of the first kind, not only $\Gamma(1)$)?

Thanks!